# NPM Read-Only File System for User

Tags: read-only, chown, npm

So I've been a bit of an idiot. I was trying to fix an NPM issue, and ran these two commands:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

[as per this suggestion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152162/npm-cannot-install-dependencies-attempt-to-unlock-something-which-hasnt-been)

And now if I try and create a folder or anything I get a 'read only file system' error.

This is only the case for the specific user, the other user account is fine. Any ideas as to how to revert the damage? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If those two are the only commands you ran, this should fix it:

```
$ sudo chown -R root:staff /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

This one reverts the effect of second command you mentioned:

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

There is nothing wrong with the first one, since home directory should've already been owned by the user herself.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do something, but I restarted the server because turning things off and on again is how I roll and now it won't boot up. :o

[Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/e46aZ4X.jpg)

Comment: None of the errors seem related to permissions and such, they seem to be about you HDD. How old is your HDD, can it be dying?

Comment: It could be. I still think it's something I've done, but I can't even get it to boot up into recovery mode or anything now.

Comment: +1 for potentially dying HDD. I ran into read-only fs errors a lot when my HDD was on its way out.